# limit_choices_to in a ForeignKey that depends on an optional field in that model class

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to `limit_choices_to` a `ForeignKey(User)` in a model called `Order`, where the `User` is limited by `User` who must be part of `Place.owner` (M2M), where that `Place` is from `Order.place`.

Sorry that was probably really confusing so I'll show you some models.

First `Order`:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    creator     = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='order_creator')
    place       = models.ForeignKey(Place, related_name='order_place')
    quote       = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    quote_owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='order_quote_owner', limit_choices_to=Q(userprofile__user_types__name='po'), null=True, blank=True)
```

Currently as you can see I have `limit_choices_to` to simply a `po` in `UserProfile.user_types.name` (that user is a property owner). But that's just a temporary solution. The `quote_owner` is a field that specify which `User` can approve the quote.

In other words, ***the property owner must be able to approve quotes for orders whose place the property owner owns.***

Here is my wild (incorrect) guess:

```
quote_owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='order_quote_owner', limit_choices_to=Q(place_set=self.place), null=True, blank=True)
```

What makes it a little complicated is that `Order.quote_owner` is optional and so is `Place.owners`. Can `limit_choices_to` be smart enough to fail silently (and not give any choices) if there are no owners specified for a place?

Anyway, here is `Place`:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name     = models.CharField(max_length=135)
    owners   = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='place_owners'  , limit_choices_to={'userprofile__user_types': 'po'}, null=True, blank=True)
```

Here is `UserProfile`:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user           = models.OneToOneField(User)
    user_types     = models.ManyToManyField(UserType, related_name='userprofile_user_types', null=True, blank=True)
    place          = models.ForeignKey(Place, related_name='userprofile_place', null=True, blank=True)
```

And finally here is `UserType`:

```
class UserType(models.Model):
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('ad', 'administrator'   ), # 1
        ('mo', 'moderator'       ), # 2
        ('vi', 'viewer'          ), # 3
        ('pm', 'property manager'), # 4
        ('po', 'property owner'  ), # 5
        ('vm', 'vendor manager'  ), # 6
        ('ve', 'vendor'          ), # 7
        ('te', 'tenant'          ), # 8
   )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
```

I kept `UserType` as an individual table because I wanted a M2M relationship between `User` and `UserType` that is still bounded by `choices`.

I welcome and appreciate any suggestions or tips. **Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, limit_choices_to cannot be used here. You need to limit the fields queryset.

I've done this before when using a generic view, so here is the code:

```
    # This class extends a generic view, but this can be any view.
class RelationCreateView(CreateView):

    def get_form(self, form_class):
        # Find all entities a user can promote within, and limit to those.
        form.fields['entity'].queryset = <SOME QUERYSET>
        return form
```

In a more simple view example:

```
def view_method():
    ...
    form.fields['field_name'].queryset = <SOME QUERYSET>
```